# Programmatically submitting a Microsoft AJAX form

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and Microsoft AJAX to create an AJAX form using this following syntax:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm()) { ... }
```

This works fine if the user clicks a submit button.  However, I also need to programmatically submit the form.  The problem is, the way MS AJAX works (for reasons that escape me) is that it puts the submit action in the `onsubmit` attribute instead of registering an event:

```
<form onsubmit="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleSubmit(..." 
    method="post" action="/Search/SearchForClients">
```

The reason this is a problem is that if you use jQuery to submit a form programmatically (i.e. `$('form').submit()`), the contents of the `onsubmit` attribute doesn't get called.

Fortunately, I found a workaround at this [site](http://paululvinius.wordpress.com/2009/03/03/how-you-dynamically-submit-a-aspnet-mvc-ajax-form-from-javascript-and-jquery/) that tells you to basically eval the contents of the `onsubmit` attribute and add it as an event handler:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) { 
    eval($(this).attr("onsubmit")); return false; 
});
```

So, my question is: are there any security issues I should be aware of when doing this?  It seems like it should be OK to me, but I want to be sure before I start adding evals to my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User can modify your page on client side with tool like Firebug and add any eval() function call he wants, but this can't break site security in any way.

Comment: Ok thanks, this was pretty much what I was thinking, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything.